# Boolean matrix where all of its row sums and column sums are the same

Tags: matrices, permutations

I'm looking for the name, in case it has a name, of a boolean matrix of order $n\times m$ where every row have the same number of entries $r$ (= same row sum), and every column have the same number of entries $c$ (= same column sum). For example, in this matrix each row sum is $3$ and each column sum is $2$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&1&0\\
1&0&1&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In particular, I would like to know if such kind of matrices can be transformed into a canonical form by using row and column permutations only (to check whether two matrices of this kind are isomorphic to each other by translating both to a canonical form and then check if they are equal), and also which other properties do they have, specially in terms of symmetries.

Comment: I guess this is the incidence matrix of a "biregular graph" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biregular_graph). The canonical form question is equivalent to solving the isomorphism problem for such graphs, which is probably as hard as the isomorphism problem for ordinary graphs.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?